# Failed to upload an image, "An error occurred at imgur"

Tags: support, bug, imgur, uploader

Currently I'm unable to upload an image to anywhere on site: e.g. posts or chat.

> [image: chat]

> [image: site]

Is this problem with Imgur?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what's happening exactly? :P

Comment: It might be helpful if you could edit the question to describe exactly how your attempts are failing, including screenshots or error messages...

Comment: @Glorfindel https://i.imgur.com/THRirsm.png, response from SE servers. No more info client-side. Like, literally, the response from `meta.stackexchange.com/upload/image` is `window.parent.displayUploadError("Failed to upload image; an error occured at imgur"); `

Comment: @Glorfindel yes, I can :-D

Comment: I've been getting the same thing for the past five minutes. The normal series of dots appear when you click `Add picture` then after what I think is a longer-than-normal time (I don't often upload images), the "_Failed to upload image; an error occured at imgur_" message appears in red. **Fairly** sure it's not a size limit as the last couple of attempts were with a severely trimmed image.

Comment: Same issue in chat.

Comment: For me, the error changed to "*Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request*"

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Im getting both.

Comment: I'm seeing it on Meta Stack Exchange when I tried to upload an image for a bug report five minutes ago.

Comment: Imgur is notorious for overloaded servers for those who browse frequently.  `one of us`

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on SO: [Image upload fails with “imgur is rejecting the request”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372133/3357935)

Comment: At least your error message was better than mine was: [`[error]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVvrr.png) I'm currently using Opera on Windows 10 Home (version: `1803`, build: `17134.165`): UA=`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.64` (Note: This happened the first couple of times I tried to upload my image. I waited a few minutes and then was able to successfully upload.)

Comment: Related: [Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313779/332286)

Comment: All I get is "enter image description" - unless someone entered an image description.  Win 7, Chrome, NA, California.

Comment: @Tim this is not a duplicate. Just look into [revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/313779/revisions) of suggested question.

Comment: @Tim for instance because uploading is not a downloading.