# Thanks Dialog not in place when flagging for "No longer needed"

Tags: bug, flags, firefox

I just flagged a comment as it was no longer needed, over at The Workplace. After flagging, the new "Thanks for flagging" green dialog appeared, but it was positioned strangely (near the corner of the Top Bar), when I recall it appeared near the flag:

[image]

This happened to me on Firefox on my Ubuntu OS.

Note that this is not a duplicate, because the other question is only about the previous case where this happens only when the comment is automatically deleted, while this problem seems to be happening all the time, even when it's not automatically deleted.

Comment: I actually like it up there... it's out of the way so i can just leave it and not have to click again to get it out of the way

Comment: Side note: don't know why but seems that my image wont load :/

Comment: thanks @Glorfindel :) now I wonder what happened to the images

Comment: Maybe related to today's image *upload* problems: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313725/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah, surely related, but I don't get *that* error, the image uploads but just wont show

Comment: I think Imgur is telling us to properly replace the template *Enter image description here* with actual content.

Comment: @PeterMortensen actually, that placeholder is the one one can fill. However, prepending the exclamation mark to such part enables the image to be displayed on the post, instead of just appearing as a link with a custom description. The image displayed is/was the issue and no the custom text on the link

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because when the other question was asked, this only happened for flags on comments that got deleted automatically, and now it's happening for flags on any comment.