# Is stack.imgur currently down?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader

I just wrote a question before this one and had trouble uploading a screenshot. The drop your image dialog throws no warning or error, but after uploading it won't show.

I also noticed that other questions won't load their images. Could this be some issue with imgur or similar?

*Example:*

[image]

When opening the image in a separate tab, Chrome gives a "too many redirects" error:

[image]

This might be linked to [Avatars aren't loading, with a status 301 (permanently moved) response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313775/avatars-arent-loading-with-a-status-301-permanently-moved-response)

Comment: Related? [Failed to upload an image, “An error occurred at imgur”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313725/300411)

Comment: I tried to check on http://isup.me/, but it looks like that's down, too...

Comment: @Nathaniel yes, related. Although I don't get the error. I "successfully" upload it but the image won't show

Comment: A few minutes ago avatars weren't loading for me, the response in my network tab was universally a status 301 (permanently moved).

Comment: @doppelgreener just right now, for me avatars are not loading also...

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's happening again. I've undeleted [my bug report about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313775/152515).

Comment: @doppelgreener avatars seem to be back, as well as images (at least on Firefox on my pc)... but now seems there are issues with chrome also

Comment: @PeterMortensen The reason the avatars are not loading is likley due to i.stack.imgur being down, so I'd favour closing in the other direction (even though it was asked earlier).

Comment: I don't have an update on this other than being more than a little angry with the state of things and that I'm working with Imgur to ensure they get it back online ASAP.

Comment: @Nick perhaps they also use hamsters to power their servers ... and haven't fed them since a few days.

Comment: You mean [this cutie](http://www.earthtechling.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/gerbil-1.jpg)?

Comment: @NickCraver thank you for your reply, we'll keep posted :)

Comment: I have seen it too on multiple SE sites: Skeptics, Psycholgoy, etc. The most annoying part is that an already ok/uploaded image can go dead if you edit the answer/question. It sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: @NickCraver: I guess SE may come to the conclusion that outsourcing all the image uploads might not have been the best idea, reliability-wise.

Comment: Checking from mobile and currently I can see pics and avatars. Dont know if its separate from web implementation w.r.t. the image storage, or if is persists on web still...

Comment: It's back on the web (at least as of) now.

Comment: @Ploni, are you still all set? For about 20 minutes, everything, including pictures and avatars, came back on Gardening, and Great Outdoors, and I was able to upload new pictures. Now we have a mixture. Some  pictures and avatars that had re-appeared stayed, some disappeared again, and new ones won't load. I logged out, cleared cookies and cache, and logged in both regular and incognito, using Firefox on Windows 10 PC.  Thanks NickCraver and everyone else for your hard work!

Comment: @Sue Yes. I'm seeing them all on here and on Judaism.SE

Comment: Everything is still dead for me. Tried answering on politics something with an image... didn't show up.

Comment: This question is not duplicate of any resolved issue, Issue still exists

Comment: @CindyMeister I would suggest to mark that one a duplicate of this one because the more general title on this question. (if it is in fact the same problem)

Comment: I can't see any i.stack.imgur -hosted pictures. I'm using Chrome on Windows and Android, and I checked IE11 on Windows as well. More notes [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4746/2).

Comment: I don't agree this question is a dupe. First because this question "does not already have an answer" (still issues), and because the target asks about issues *uploading* images, whereas here it is asked about the display of images itself independent from the upload process

Comment: This is STILL a problem, no images are showing. I'm using a California-based VPN, multiple machines, all browsers.

Comment: When I shift-F5 (hard refresh) pages with images I couldn't see before, I can now see them.

Comment: A issue with CloudFront?

Comment: so, @NickCraver I haven't seen the issue in a while now, was this solved somehow? (I pinged you cause you are the only diamond up here). I wonder if other users still experience this issue...

Comment: Marking this completed because, *as far as I can tell*, it is fixed. However... There was some seriously dodgy stuff happening; if anyone is still affected, please let me know.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree, I haven't seen issues for a while now, nor other's reporting theirs... thanks for the follow up

Comment: I don't think this has been fixed at all.

Comment: Why, do you see it again? I'm currently mobile so I'll check tomorrow

Answer (score 15):

Sorry for the answer, but this is too long for a comment:

In both Washington and California (San Diego VPN), the url
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yufyl.jpg
is returning

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 15:13:49 GMT
Expires: Wed, 15 Aug 2018 15:13:49 GMT
Location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yufyl.jpg
Server: nginx
Age: 8570
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 26bf46825c6bd12542772bad5a4d97b5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: jdUTshS_K0gqJp0E0TWmQ7CUh3mbm0MdiDGSO4wJt3pKhgf9lhWc7g==
```

Notice that it's redirecting back to itself.  This causes an infinite redirection loop, which the browser detects and kills.

This is a server configuration issue that only the `stack.imgur` admins can address.

Comment: I live in San Diego and it works sporadically for me.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog perhaps caching or something on your PC makes it appear sporadically. Or well distributed servers hosting the images. I too notice over here (Central America) that pics come and go

Comment: For me (Poland) this is still broken and most of avatars does not display. It works if I use Opera built-in VPN ("Europa" as a region), so this is definitely a issue with some local imgur servers.

Comment: Same from Germany.

Answer (score -14):

It seems to be back up right now in most areas.

Some users who are still experiencing the issue should consider clearing their browser cache.

I guess they've harassed imgur enough until they fixed it.

Comment: I still don't see them. :(

Comment: @Catija it's likely a caching issue for you, if you open it in a diff browser or possibly just Incognito mode, it should work. (you can always clear cookies too)

Comment: Or there's multiple servers...

Comment: @Catija just tested with connecting my VPN to TX, still seems to work.

Comment: Literally just came back minutes ago here in NZ. Couldn't reach i.stack.imgur.com.

Comment: Still down for me (in FR).

Comment: Still issues in the USA too.

Comment: For me it's working now, but I had to clear the cache. (I'm in the USA)

Comment: @DonaldDuck That likely didn't actually fix your problem, it was probably coincidence that that "fixed" it.