# Unable to see any image

Tags: support, chat, images, imgur

I have tried all browsers and even the mobile app but I am unable to see any picture that's there, in questions/ answers/ chat.

[image]

[image]

From physics chatroom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez5wF.jpg

As evidence, here are two pictures^ . I have uploaded them but am unable to see them, it reads "enter image description here". 
I have tried:

- Logging out then logging in
- Clearing brwosing data and then logging again
- As aforementioned, mobile chat, mobile app, web browsers like Mozilla
  firefox, Microsoft edge, google chrome.
- Turned off the laptop and restarted.

Please fix this.

Comment: They render fine, is imgur.com perhaps blocked at your location?

Comment: having same issue. think its cloud related ie some servers/ regions in the imgur cloud are malfunctioning. using chrome/ US, windows, ipad. some of the chat avatars (images) are failing to load for some chat rooms (`mathematics` bad but `physics` ok). same image seemed to load in one region (poland) but not US. see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down

Comment: Just noticed. Having the same issue.

Comment: @TimPost imgur is down for many people around the world for over 20 hours now. (at least the stack sub domain)